# fill_between function using axline as input generates TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm attempting to use an [axline](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axline.html) as one of the inputs to the `matplotlib` (version 3.4.3) [fill_between()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) function.  Simplified code example code below.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set my figure size
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 3.50]

# Define a linear space between -5 and 5, with 100 points
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

# Define the Intercept and Slope
intercept0 = 2.2
slope0 = 0.75

# Set the x and y limits for the plot
plt.xlim(-5,5)
plt.ylim(-5,5)

# Create a diagonal line through [0,2.2] with a slope of 0.75
diagline = plt.axline((0,intercept0), slope=slope0, color='C0')

# Fill the area between the diagonal line and y=0
plt.fill_between(x,diagline,0)

plt.show()
```

---

When I run that code, I get the following `numpy` error.

**Error:**

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Is there a way to use the `axline` as an input for the `fill_between()` function?  I've seen vertical and horizontal lines used as inputs to `fill_between()`, as well as curved lines (sines), but I cannot find examples of diagonals created with `axline`.

Comment: `fill_between` wants an array of numbers, not an artist

Comment: @PaulH Thanks, that makes sense.  Is it possible to calculate where an artist (axline) intersects an x or y limit?  I could use that to generate a linspace for y.

Never mind, I just answered my own question.  I've got the slope and the starting intersect.  It's just a matter of simple geometry at that point.

Comment: I would compute the y-values of the line directly from your existing `x` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the line is just `slope0 * x + intercept0`, which numpy can use unchanged. So, you can do the fill with `plt.fill_between(x, slope0 * x + intercept0)`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set my figure size
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 3.50]

# Define a linear space between -5 and 5, with 100 points
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

# Define the Intercept and Slope
intercept0 = 2.2
slope0 = 0.75

# Set the x and y limits for the plot
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)

# Create a diagonal line through [0,2.2] with a slope of 0.75
diagline = plt.axline((0, intercept0), slope=slope0, color='C0')

# Fill the area between the diagonal line and y=0
plt.fill_between(x, slope0 * x + intercept0, 0, facecolor='gold', alpha=0.4, edgecolor='r', hatch='xx')
plt.show()
```

[image: fill_between up till a diagonal line]

PS: If you only want to show the positive part, you could use the `where` parameter:

```py
y0 =  slope0 * x + intercept0
plt.fill_between(x, y0, 0, where=y0 >= 0, interpolate=True, color='yellow')
plt.axhline(0, color='black') # shows the x-axis at y=0
```

[image: fill between, only showing positive part]